# Solr 4 returns 0 results for queries but returns results for "*:*" queries

Tags: solr

I just upgraded from solr3 to solr4, in the process I've dropped the old data and re-imported my documents.

However, oddly enough, when I run a /select?q=* query I get results returned as expected, but when I pick out a word from the results of the query above and run it, I get 0 results. Any query other than * returns 0 results.

I'm perplexed and looking for a path to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you might be relying on the default search field which has been deprecated from Solr 3.6.
Check [SOLR-2724 - Deprecate defaultSearchField and defaultOperator defined in schema.xml](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2724).

You can add `qf` param with the field to be searched upon in the request handler.

Add the `df` parameter to your query request handler. It names the default field.
You can also use the `qf` with the edismax query parser.

Comment: I think you're spot on, but I'm not quite teasing out the solution yet. df is set to the unique id field, and in the debug output it was indeed changing the query to id:search_term, but isn't this supposed to be "fl" (field list)? I'm not quite sure what configuration needs to change here.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of eDisMax qf parameter as the list of fields to search. Because 'fl' is the list of fields to return as part of results (as opposed to all of them). Do you have eDisMax enabled and qf defined?